# Initialise 2D array pointer to char globally

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a 2-dimensional array of pointer to char and initialising it in a header file.
The problem is this: it doesn't complain getting assigned a `const char[]` but does not like me assigning `const char*` (as shown in the code). It gives me an error "initializer element is not constant".

```
const char lang[8] = "English";

const char * langPtr = "English 1";

const char * optionPtr[3][10] = {

    {lang, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },

    {langPtr, 0, ...},    

    {...}

};
```

I thought `lang` and `langPtr` are both pointing at the beginning of a string so should be able to do this. I want to use a pointer to initialise the 2D array. Is there anyway of doing this globally?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I tested it in Visual Studio 2010 and it compiled fine.

Comment: Oh really? 
I'm actually using MPLAB C30 compiler. It's GCC-based though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, elements in initialisers for static objects must be "constant expressions" (all global objects are static).

The address of a static object is an "address constant", which is a kind of "constant expression" - that's why `lang` works.  The value of a variable - even a `const` variable (though note that `langPtr` itself is not `const`) - is *not* a "constant expression", which is why `langPtr` does not work.

Note that this is different in C++, where `const` qualified variables are genuine constants.

Comment: Ok cool. You sort of confirmed what I thought was happening. Suppose I have to look at another way of achieving my task.. Thanks guys!

Comment: @ilikeC normal practise is to show some appreciation by upvoting.

Answer (score 0):

*langPtr is the character 'E', not a pointer to that character.

Edit: Whoops the question has changed and you are now using langPtr not *langPtr. I'll have another look.

Hmmm. Okay sorry I should probably be offering comments rather than an answer, but having started an answer I'll continue it.

Interestingly your code compiles fine in C++ rather than C, which we can probably take as an indicator that the problem is a subtle one.

The compiler's error message is literally correct. The identifier langPtr is a variable not a constant, since you can change langPtr to point at other const char s.

One work around is to substitute the string literal "English 1" rather than use langPtr in the array. The same workaround expressed slightly differently is to use the preprocessor to define langPtr instead, so;

```
#define langPtr "English 1"
```

Admittedly this is ugly, but maybe it will meet your needs.

Finally, I would counsel against initializing any array in a header file. Declare variables in header files. Define (i.e. initialize) variables in .c files.

Good luck.